# Google Tag Manager - Track Linked In Shares from Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to track Linked In shares via Google Tag Manager to Google Analytics but I am struggling with it. Facebook likes and Twitter tweets we are currently tracking succesfully, but we struggle to track the LinkedIn share from button on blog post.

Do you have some idea or experience how to do that, please?

Is there some smooth way to achieve how many Linked In shares there were from certain blog post?

Comment: Are your social share buttons implemented by a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Hi,it is implemented via wordpress plugin for disqus